# Sed move text before delimiter

Tags: regex, sed, awk

I have a csv file that looks like this:

```
"foo","bar","lorem","ipsum"
"foo"."bar","XX lorem","ipsum"
```

I need to transform the fields beginning with "xx " in fields ending with " xx":

```
"foo","bar","lorem","ipsum"
"foo"."bar","lorem xx","ipsum"
```

Can sed (or awk) help me? ("xx " is a string not a regexp result)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sed -r 's/XX ([^"]+)/\1 XX/' filename
```

Answer (score 4):

```
sed -r 's/"(XX) ([^"]*)"/"\2 \1"/g'
```

test:

```
kent$  echo '"foo","bar","lorem","ipsum XX"
"foo"."XX bar","XX lorem","ips XX um"'|sed -r 's/"(XX) ([^"]*)"/"\2 \1"/g'
"foo","bar","lorem","ipsum XX"
"foo"."bar XX","lorem XX","ips XX um"
```

**Note**:

- this will do this logic on all fields, which starts with XX.
- XX in field, but not at the starting point, will be ignored (see example above)
- **!!! if XX has characters which have special meaning in regex, the command may fail. for example if XX is `.*`**